# How to create alias to another keyword in rust

Tags: rust, metaprogramming, keyword

Is it possible in Rust to create new keywords that function as an alias to another keyword?

For example, create keyword `fun` that points to `fn` and use it as if it were `fn`:

```rust
// somehow alias `fun` to `fn`

fun main() {
  println!("Hello, world!")
}
```

If possible, how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for an alternative to C's `#define`, there is nothing that will allow arbitrary words to be used as keywords (which is probably a good thing).

If you are looking to alias a type, Rust has [`type`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.type.html), which can be used to to rename `i64` to `int` like this: `type int = i64;`, for example.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you can do this via procedural macro, since it is just "string transformation".

You cant use crate [dtolnay/syn](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn) to simplify the work.

Comment: You cannot do what the OP is looking for. You can only wrap the whole fn in a macro that will transform it, and you don't even need a procedural macro for that.